# Error "Data too long for column" when executing stored procedure via c# mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql, database, stored-procedures

I am writing a C# application that will access a MySQL Database using a stored procedure with 5 parameters:

```
in startTime varchar(20), 
in endTime varchar(20), 
in tagID Int,
in FullDay Int,
in iteration Int
```

that returns 3 variables all integers.
When executing the MySQLCommand I get the error: "Data too long for column 'startTime' at row 41".

Here is my code:

```
//create command
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetArchiveData", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("startTime", startIn);
cmd.Parameters["startTime"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("endTime", endIn);
cmd.Parameters["endTime"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tagID", tagIn);
cmd.Parameters["tagID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FullDay", fdIn);
cmd.Parameters["FullDay"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("iteration", iterationIn);
cmd.Parameters["iteration"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}
MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    TagData tagData = new TagData();
    tagData.TagID = tagIn;
    tagData.Dsttimestamp = Convert.ToInt32(dr["timestamp"]);
    tagData.PvValue = Convert.ToInt32(dr["sp"]);
    tagData.PvValue = Convert.ToInt32(dr["pv"]);

    tagDataList.Add(tagData);
}
dr.Close();

this.CloseConnection();
return tagDataList;
```

If anyone knows why this would happen and why the first occurrence would be row 41 it would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Removing the Single quotations that are required in the MySQL statement in workbench from the strings startIn and endIn has solved that issue. MySQL uses single quotes to define strings where the C# variable is already declared as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is in the sproc.
Have you looked at the vaklue you are passing in to it?
It just seems the value is too long for the column so looking at what is being passed will let you know for sure.

Comment: in this scenario the variable startIn which gets passed in as startTime is equal to "2015-11-09 11-31-00" and will always be passed in as this format, if i call the procedure via mysql workbench it works

Comment: Actually the string is included with the ' single quotes either side of the string, could this be an issue?

Comment: Well that would be another 2 chars so probably.
You could debug, break on the line and modify the value to remove them and see if that let's you know.

Answer (score 0):

**Inserting value is too long for the column.** 
Please debug and Check whether u are inserting correct type of data or correct type value for the column.
There is an hard limit on how much data can be stored in a single row of a mysql table, regardless of the number of columns or the individual column length.

Comment: in this scenario the variable startIn which gets passed in as startTime is equal to "2015-11-09 11-31-00" and will always be passed in as this format, if i call the procedure via mysql workbench it works